# Difference between $.proxy, bind, call, apply

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, this, anonymous-function

The old way:

```
var self = this;    
setTimeout(function(){
  console.log(self);
}, 5000);
```

With jQuery:

```
setTimeout($.proxy(function(){
  console.log(this);
}, this), 5000);
```

With bind:

```
setTimeout((function(){
  console.log(this);
}).bind(this), 5000);
```

With call:

```
setTimeout((function(){
  console.log(this);
}).call(this), 5000);
```

It seems that apply works too:

```
setTimeout((function(){
  console.log(this);
}).apply(this), 5000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SYajz/1/

I was wondering if there are any not so obvious differences between these methods

Comment: your last two examples don't work - they invoke the callback immediately.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Right, so we've got three styles of calling a function here. They are all ways of addressing the problem of *context*, i.e. that the `this` keyword will have a different value depending on how the function is called.

## Aliasing

```
var self = this;    
setTimeout(function(){
  console.log(self);
}, 5000);
```

This is a very simple way. It simply sets a new variable that won't be overridden within the function. The value is closed in, so when the function is called after the timeout, `self` will be what you expect.

## Binding

```
setTimeout($.proxy(function(){
  console.log(this);
}, this), 5000);

setTimeout((function(){
  console.log(this);
}).bind(this), 5000);
```

These two functions have identical results. This is because [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy) does exactly the same thing as [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). `bind`, however, is a new syntax that isn't supported by some older browsers.

This works by permanently "binding" a context to a function. This means that, however the function is called, the value of `this` will always be the value of the first argument to `bind`.

## `call`/`apply`

```
setTimeout((function(){
  console.log(this);
}).call(this), 5000);

setTimeout((function(){
  console.log(this);
}).apply(this), 5000);
```

Again, these two functions are identical. The only difference between [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) is what other parameters are sent to a function. `call` expects a list (e.g. `fn.call(context, param1, param2)`) whereas `apply` expects an array (`fn.apply(context, [param1, param2])`).

What both these functions do is call the function with a particular context specified.

However, neither of these functions does what you want. They both call the function immediately with a certain context, rather than waiting 5 seconds to do so. That's because `call` and `apply` work just like `()`: the code is executed immediately.

## Conclusion

Which method is more suitable will depend on your task. For simple operations, aliasing might well do the job. But it's worth remembering that that introduces another variable, and that the context can't be set at call-time. The other methods also have their strengths in different situations, particularly when writing a library where users are supplying callback functions.

Answer (score 4):

With `$.proxy` and `.bind()`, you're creating a new function that has its `this` value bound to the value you provided. So that's the function that gets passed to `setTimeout()`.

---

With `.call()` and `.apply()` you're invoking the function immediately, so it's not going to wait for the timer.

For those to work with the timer, you'd need to return a function that closes over a variable that references the provided `this` value, and invokes the `console.log()` given the referenced `this`.

```
setTimeout((function(){
  var that = this;
  return function() {
      console.log(that);
  }
}).call(this), 5000);
```